# How to run a script and enter an argument before running it

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'd like to know how can I run a script in cmd and enter the arguments before it even runs, I tried googling it but I don't know how to describe it.
Anyways, this is what I'm trying to do

```
C:> script.bat 2 4
```

so basically run the script with 2 and 4 as variables and be able to use them inside the script for different actions.
Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Something like this: `if "%1"=="" set /p "VAR1=Enter 1-st variable value: "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> script.bat 2 4

the values you give are Arguments but internally are Parameters %1 to %9 so its very common and easily done to mix the terms. (Parameter %0 is usually the script name so Script.Bat with its path is often used as %~dp0)

```
@echo off
set "arg1=%1"
if "%2"=="" echo Silly Billy I need 2 arguments & pause & exit
set "arg2=%2"
echo Parameter 1 is =%arg1%
echo Parameter 2 is =%arg2%
pause and continue
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to declare them as variables:

```
set location=Stackoverflow
set user=Noft

C:> script.bat %location% %user%
```

Comment: I think they're asking how to use the arguments that get passed in to the script as variables (`%1`, `%2`, etc.) but I'm not positive.